# How to “connect” the data from one table to another table without using EF in Visual Studio is it possible to use existing controller?

Tags: sql-server

I have many tables it is related to one table to another table how to connect tables in existing controller in Visual Studio without using Entity Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Entity Framework, you might also use "plain" ADO.NET in your MVC-application, involving:

- a SqlConnection object to make a connection to the database server,
- a SqlCommand object to define a SQL query to execute and
- a SqlDataReader object or a DataTable object to read/fetch the query
  results.

Using ADO.NET has a number of benefits and a number of drawbacks, however. Discussions are quite intense on the Internet. I'm an old guy and I personally prefer plain ADO.NET, but when starting with a C# MVC application, using Entity Framework might be easier, since almost all tutorials and documentation use it too.

But why you do not want to use Entity Framework? Recent versions are quite fine and stable and perform fairly well in most scenarios. But that's a design choice you alone can make for yourself (or you should discuss this within your dev team.)

Comment: how to connect one table to another table using getter and setter method,in database side i used primary key and foreign key relation

Comment: When you say "getter/setter methods" I think about Entity Framework (EF). In plain ADO.NET, however, you provide a textual SQL query that gets executed on the database server and retrieve the query results for further processing in your application. You need to join any tables inside the SQL query you provide. So I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. Perhaps we are talking about different things when we speak of "Entity Framework"?

Comment: k now i created project using entity framework, in model folder some .cs files would created in controller folder which file can i create which code can i add

Comment: OK. When I am not mistaken, the classes in your model folder represent your database tables. Correct? In your controller you can use a LINQ query that targets those classes. It's quite difficult for me to explain in detail how to use Entity Framework. Perhaps you should look at some examples/walktroughs on Microsoft's website first (or any other site, like StackOverflow, that might contain some good examples ;)).

Comment: I have two tables are related to primary key and foreign key relation one table I created in controller it is working fine but how to connect with another table when I created another table in controller section I got error like The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: Seems that this has more to do with your controllers structure. Somehow your application seems not to be able to map the URL you use to a controller action method. You might need to investigate this somewhat further. If your application works fine with one table, but fails when adding a separate table, please try to isolate the exact issue step by step. Try to find out what this issue relates to. And then post a new question on StackOverflow. I personally think it has nothing (or at least very little) to do with Entity Framework alone.

Comment: could you plz  post here bulk update,delete,select and insert code
using entity framework.

Comment: I think that's not possible with Entity Framework. Entity Framework is just used for generating/mapping an object model in your application to your database table and procedure structures, so that you can query it in your application using that object model instead of directly using SQL queries. As far as I know, Entity Framework does not support bulk operations, unless it is possible to let it directly execute specific SQL statements as well. Perhaps this question of yours deserves its own separate question/post on StackOverflow...

Comment: DateTime start = Customer.Timestamp; I  write this code on controller section how can I fetch the value in html file I used entity framework

Comment: how can I improve bulk operation performance when I inserted 1lack record its taken 110mins I am using entity framework